# Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration

Tags: javascript, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Asp .Net MVC Kendo Ui. I am getting this error 'Failed to execute **'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration'** in java script  on production server but not able to replicate in local system. Please help me.

Comment: Can you show us some code under which context the error is being thrown. Any kind of stackTrace, logs?

Comment: Actually this error log has been captured on production server through Relic tools that's why i don't have more details

Comment: Someone can replicate this error. When this error come?